# Select multiple rows from table based on ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

```
ID  KEY
15  hello
16  world
17  done
```

I want to select rows 15 and 17. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERSMETA where ID=15,17
```

But it’s not working. What can I do instead?

Comment: Plain text is better than image, we can't cut and paste from an image.

Comment: Also, learn the difference between row and column. `ID` and `KEY` are columns, `15` and `17` are the IDs of rows.

Comment: hahaha i did good mistake by saying column instead of row. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM USERSMETA where ID in(15,17);
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM USERSMETA where ID=15 OR ID=17;
```

Comment: this one is really perfect . Thank You ..it even works if i have to select 100 rows using php

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to get these two rows (not columns)

```
SELECT * FROM USERSMETA WHERE ID = 15 OR ID = 17
```

Comment: you are missing = sign here `ID 17`